# form onSubmit triggers the wrong button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, addeventlistener

I have a form with an input and two buttons, one is "button" cancel, one is "input" submit. However when I press return key on input, the onSubmit event triggers on button depending on their position on HTML DOM. Here is the simplified code

```
// cancel button goes first
<form id="form">
  <input>
  <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

const cancelButton = document.getElementById('cancel');
const form = document.getElementById('form');

cancelButton.addEventListener('click', () => { console.log('cancel') });
form.addEventListener('submit', () => { console.log('submit') });
```

When I press return on input, it will log "cancel". However if I put submit button first, I will log normally "submit".

How is this possible that return key will trigger listener on cancel button?

Comment: what are the variables `cancelButton` and `form` - you haven't shown what these represent

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry I was too lazy, let me put them on.

Comment: I know it may be obvious, just wanted to rule out silly typos :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, this is just kind of pseudo code, the code is more complicated. But let me see if there is typo.

Comment: @h1b9b answer is good, but as an aside ... why don't you stick with the same kind of objects? `<button type="button">Cancel</button>` and `<button type="submit">Submit</button> -- or make them both `<input type="..">` elements.  Either way you're hooking up event handlers to both of them. It just seems more consistent in the design if they're both the same _kind_ of thing.

Comment: @StephenP The reason I put as submit as input is accessibility issue, but I guess I can make cancel button an input tag also. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default a `button` tag type is `submit`
So you should specify the type to avoid this problem

cf: Tips & notes section in https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

```js
const cancelButton = document.getElementById('cancel');
const form =  document.getElementById('form');
cancelButton.addEventListener('click', () => { console.log('cancel') });
form.addEventListener('submit', () => { console.log('submit') });
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input>
  <button type="button" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: Thank you so much! But I just found out that onSubmit is not working lol, when I press return it won't log anything

Comment: not working? in this example, by pressing return the console.log is executed and the form is posted so if you don't preserve logs in your console you won't see anything. you can also `preventDefault` to stop the event propagation

Comment: @h1b9b Yes, I put preventDefault, but pressing return won't even go into the function(I put breakpoint on them)

Comment: @h1b9b I found out that if I add listener to submit button, pressing return will trigger on that listener, but listener on form is never triggered. It's weird cause yesterday it was fine.

Comment: That's weird, cause in the snippet the listener is triggered. I have no idea what could cause it. But I think that a listener on the click event on the submit button would be better as it will always trigger before the form submit event

Comment: @h1b9b I see, it is working fine with adding listener on button but I just wonder why it's not working, I just remember this morning it still worked fine lol. But anyway thank you very much, I'll try to figure out what happened.

Comment: @h1b9b one more question, why the listener on button will always trigger before form submit?